# How to view pub year based on xml:id through XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

i am using this code in xml

**Reference citation LINKS in XML:**

```
   Boulos <link href="#bib-0014"/>
```

**Corresponding Reference:**

```
  <bib xml:id="bib-0014"><citation type="journal" xml:id="cit-0014"><author><familyName>Boulos</familyName>, <givenNames>L</givenNames></author>. **<pubYear year="1974">1974a</pubYear>**. <articleTitle>R&#x00E9;vision syst&#x00E9;matique du genre <i>Sonchus</i> L. s.l. V. Sous&#x2010;genre 2. <i>Dendrosonchus</i>. &#x2013; Bot</articleTitle>. <journalTitle>Not</journalTitle>. <vol>127</vol>: <pageFirst>7</pageFirst>&#x2013;<pageLast>37</pageLast>.</citation></bib>
```

**Figure citation LINKS in XML:**

```
   Fig <link href="#ecog340-fig-0001"/>
```

**Corresponding figure:**

```
      <figure xml:id="ecog340-fig-0001">
      <mediaResourceGroup>
      <mediaResource alt="image" href="urn:x-wiley:16000587:media:ecog340:ecog340-fig-0001"/>
      <mediaResource alt="image" mimeType="image/png" href="image_n/ecog340-fig-0001.png" rendition="webOriginal" />
      <mediaResource alt="image" mimeType="image/gif" href="image_t/ecog340-fig-0001-t.gif" rendition="webLoRes" />
      <mediaResource alt="image" mimeType="image/png" href="image_m/ecog340-fig-0001-m.png" rendition="webHiRes" />
      </mediaResourceGroup>
      <caption>
      <p>........</p>
      </caption>
      </figure>
```

**Table citation LINKS in XML:**

```
   Table <link href="#ecog340-tbl-1"/>
```

**Corresponding Table:**

```
    <tabular xml:id="ecog340-tbl-1">
    <title type="main">......</title>
```

using in XSLT:

```
    <xsl:template match="link">
    <a href="{@href}"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
    </a>
    </xsl:template>
```

In Browserview:

Boulos #bib-0014

Fig #ecog340-fig-0001

Table #ecog340-tbl-1

But i want it should view to all the reference links with the year

Boulos 1974a

With number (based on id - omit the zeros)

Fig 1

With number (based on id)

Table 1

Could you please?

Comment: Thanks Ian Roberts. now i have edited this post, due to some discrepancies in my XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd define a key

```
<xsl:key name="bibById" match="bib" use="@xml:id"/>
```

Then in the `link` template you can get the year with

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('bibById', substring-after(@href, '#'))/citation/pubYear" />
```

Extending the question to tables and figures as well, I'd adopt a slightly more flexible approach - allow the key to take in `figure` and `tabular` elements as well as `bib`:

```
<xsl:key name="xrefById" match="bib|tabular|figure" use="@xml:id"/>
```

And define templates in a special *mode* to handle the various cases

```
<xsl:template match="bib" mode="xref">
  <xsl:value-of select="citation/pubYear" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="xref">
  <!-- take everything after the second dash in the id and treat as number -->
  <xsl:value-of select="
         number(substring-after(substring-after(@xml:id, '-'), '-'))" />
</xsl:template>
```

Now in the `link` template you can use

```
<xsl:template match="link">
  <a href="{@href}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('bibById', substring-after(@href, '#'))"
                         mode="xref" /> 
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

and it will do the right thing for each kind of cross-reference.